# Why are some domains allowed to use a self signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I noticed that the SSL certificate for `https://www.google.com` appears to be a self signed certificate, verified by Google Inc.

[image]

Any other website I encounter with a self signed certificate gets yelled at by my browser and I have to add exceptions to view them.

Why does Google get the pass here?

Comment: Actually, it is not self-signed certificate. It is CA-signed certificate. This is why you don't experience any issues.

Comment: Here is a definition of self-signed certificate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate